# Receiving the value from redux store using this.props becomes available only on the second time of the button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am dispatching the api response to redux store and retrieve the same using the click of the button `Generate Report`.I am trying to get the data to be downloaded through csv (not to be shown right-away in UI) using `this.props.reportData`. `this.props.reportData` is should be available through the following code :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reportData:
      state.reducerReport &&
      state.reducerReport.reportData
        ? state.reducerReport.reportData
        : []
  };
};
```

The `this.props.reportData` is very well available in `render()` method when tried the following code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.reportData)}; // able to view the data
        <button onClick={this.generateReport}>
          Generate Report
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't want to show the `reportData` in the `render()` method, instead it should be available in `generateReport()` event. This way I can download the data by parsing `json` to `csv`. The sample code is given below:

```
generateReport() {

    if (
      this.props.reportData &&
      this.props.reportData.length > 0
    ) {
      let csvContent = papa.unparse(this.props.reportData);
      this.download(
        csvContent,
        "report.csv",
        "text/csv;encoding:utf-8"
      );
    }
  }
```

The issue is `this.props.reportData` becomes available only on the second click of `button`.

Comment: So prior to and after the first click of the `<button>`  you're seeing data rendered by `{ JSON.stringify(this.props.reportData) }`? Is `papa.unparse()` , or `this.download()` throwing an exception?

Comment: @DacreDenny Yes. proper to and after the first click of the <button>, i am able to the data by `{ JSON.stringify(this.props.reportData) }`. There is no error thrown at the first click of the `<button>`

Comment: What do you get in `this.props.reportData` in `generateReport` when you click first time?

Comment: @randomSoul empty json

Comment: @Prem - Bind this to your `generateReport` call - `<button onClick={this.generateReport.bind(this)}>`